# how i can Import data from Database ( My Sql) to another website

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I need to show data from another website in my website,
i had control panel for tow site but i need it dynamic way to connect them

```
   website 1         website 2 
    *****              *****
    * A * <<<< =Data== * B *
    *****              *****
```

so i write

```
$link = @mysql_connect("Ip Addres to another website","username for mysql 2","passowrd 2 ")or die("Couldn't make connection.");

    @mysql_select_db("qatarlab_test",$link)or die("Couldn't select database");

    $factorRes = @mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM `factor` ");

    $factorRow = @mysql_fetch_array($factorRes);        

    echo  $factorRow[0];
```

but nothing happen

Comment: Do you have to do this in PHP? Do you have shell access or remote mysql access for example?

Comment: If you remove the error suppressors (@) you might find out something; most likely the user doesn't have permissions to access the database outside the allowed IPs

Comment: ofcourse you use connexion parameters of the second site in your code of first site

Comment: yes i have c panel for tow website id do what you ask me to try but 
steel the same thing

Comment: please can any one show my how to do it in write way or correct my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you must enable remote database connection in the original site so that the new site can connect to it. you can do this in the control panel->Database(Remote Database Connection) of the original site.

You could specify the IP or domain of the new site to that it allows only the new site to connect or you could just add wildcard (%) to allow any external connection to the database.

when this is done, run ur query again.

hope it helps

Comment: yes thank you allot but this ide not clear for me 
**"add wildcard (%) to allow any external connection to the database"**

Comment: if u want only ur IP or domain name to access the database server remotely add "80.76.89.70"(ur ip) or "urdomain.com"(ur domain). if you want to open ur database to any remote address (any website connecting externally) just put "%" in the box. It is called wildcard. % means connect anyone from anywhere who has correct login info. pls tell me if u re stil confused. i will be happy to break it down more.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try code given below,

```
$link = @mysql_connect("Ip Addres to another website","username for mysql 2","passowrd 2 ")or die("Couldn't make connection.") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("qatarlab_test",$link)or die("Couldn't select database", $link) or die(mysql_error());

$factorRes = @mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM `factor` " , $link) or die(mysql_error());

$factorRow = @mysql_fetch_array($factorRes);        

echo "<pre>";
print_r($factorRow);
echo "</pre>";
```

Here  `$link` will be for specific database connection and `die(mysql_error())` for if any error in or query or database connection.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your first line: mysql_connect you are passing the IP Address and Username for connecting the DB.

Make sure that the user has the privilege to connect to the DB remotely (i.e. via a machine other than the Localhost). In general, when a user is added in the DB its default access is for the localhost. Check out this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

You basically need to add user using: CREATE USER 'admin'@'IP Address of Website 1'; All the CPanel's have this provision in their interface as well.

Comment: i create database in "website 2" and user2 to control with database 2 in a website , but did you mean another user have can controls database outside ????

Comment: O Yes ! You need to create another user which has the priviledge to access the DB from a different IP Address. User2 by default will only be able to access the DB when the DB Server is Localhost

Comment: how i can give this user privileges  to accesses from different IP